# Behavior of anonymous block, is it compiled every reuse in oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, server-side, rdbms

I was reading Oracle DB Concept Guide ( 11g r2 ) and i just see this article 8- 9 PL/SQL Anonymous block and in this article it has a table and it name is **Differences Between Anonymous Blocks and Subprograms** ;

And concepts says for anonymous block " **Compiled with ever reuse : NO** " when i read this sentence i get it but after this sentence concepts say this picture.

Im confused right now because they said every reuse *its not compiled* but they say again **Unlike triggers, an anonymous block is compiled each time it is loaded into memory**

Am i wrong about the confusion or am i right ? I think it has simple explanation but i didnt get it :)

Thanks for your help ,

Source ; [Oracle Concept Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/srvrside.htm#CHDJGEBD)

Comment: Code that is not used regularly is aged out of memory, because RAM is a valuable and (even now) scarce resource.

Answer (score 0):

in simple words: oracle compiles anonymous block but saves the result in the shared pool of SGA. for example if you restart server it will to be recompiled

see more info from the document from your link:

> Oracle Database compiles the PL/SQL block and places it in the shared
>   pool of the SGA, but it does not store the source code or compiled
>   version in the database for reuse beyond the current instance.

Comment: they're not saying about the result but i get what you mean :) I have one more question for you.For example , in my anonymous block i call some procedure(with 2 parameters) and it's returning some values , is oracle save all results in SGA ?